# Switch 4-player 2 controller split-screen games catalog?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I have a few friends coming over but only 2 controllers.
Is there a catalog for 4-player split-screen games we could play with just 2 controllers (an example of such a game: Just Dance 2022)?
The official Nintendo site offers just a number of players filtering, not to dream of local/online, and "half-controller" flag.